# How to send GET request with google OAuth2 and Java to script.google.com web page?

Tags: java, google-apps-script, oauth, get, google-oauth

GET is working for me but I get google services authorization page when I send it. I read guides from google but still don't understand how to use Credentials right.

This [thing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/java) is for managing script files itself and have nothing to do with my problem :/

Would be decent if it is possible in Java

Comment: Your question does not offer enough information for people to be able to help you. Which document are you accessing, what's your code, how do your request and response look?

Comment: Could you share the code you're working on? Would making the web app publicly accessible be an option here?

Comment: @Iamblichus made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533751/how-to-get-info-from-script-google-com-web-page-with-java

Comment: @Taschi ^^^^^^^

Comment: Your new question is hardly more clear than this one. If you were asking the same, you can just edit your original question, no need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

After  sign in google you will be redirected on redirect page with google code. Redirect page could be set in google private user console. When you will get google code you could use code for obtaining jwt with GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

for example

```
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest googleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest = codeFlow.newTokenRequest(code)
        .setRedirectUri(redirectUrl);
    try {
        GoogleTokenResponse googleTokenResponse = googleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ExternalAuthenticationException("Invalid google 'code' parameter (disposable)");
    }
```