# How to get info from script.google.com web page with Java?

Tags: java, google-apps-script, oauth, google-oauth

So, I have my [script page](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzvHqXSXY0LgwfFeltbNS_iYCcge8re0s-uY0-lvSJ0uuMDENoS/exec?message=hello&langin=en&langout=ru) and I want to get an output that generates on this page. It could've been done with default http client but the problem is that google requires authorization to access this page.
So how can I do it right?
I also [asked about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477491/how-to-send-get-request-with-google-oauth2-and-java-to-script-google-com-web-pag) but now I realize that my question wasn't clear.

Comment: Questions about web applications must include how the app is published: 1. Execute as"Me"/"User accessing the web-app". 2.Access:" Anyone"/"Anyone even anonymous". See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script-web-application/info) for more details.

Comment: Show your Java code. Easiest way is to publish the script to execute as "Me"/" Anyone even anonymous"

Comment: If you already asked the same question and it was unclear, please edit your 1st question and don't ask 2 times the same thing. Anyways, we need more details to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to post web app page to be accessible by "anyone even anonymous". So no auth is needed